# Ubuntu Server 19.10 - External Disk Unmounts Itself

Tags: server, mount, hard-drive, 19.10

Since upgrading to Ubuntu Server 19.10, the external HDD attached to the computer disappears from its mount-point after a while, I think likely when the disk spins down/is idling.

When the disk "unmounts", it is still visible when running

```
blkid
```

and other disk list commands, and even when unplugging the USB and reattaching the drive, it doesn't remount to its folder, and the only way to get it to show up again is to run the mount command manually.

Interestingly, the drive still connects automatically when rebooting the system through the fstab file, but once it's gone, it will only reappear via the mount command or another reboot.

I'm hoping to find a solution to this as I'm using the server as a remote system, to I'm not there very often to fix issues, and I'm currently having to SSH to run mount every time I want to access it!

Thanks!

Edit: This never happened before on Server 18.10 or 19.04, it's only after upgrading to Server 19.10 that this has started happening.

Comment: Look at `journalctl -b 0 _EXE=/usr/lib/udisks2/udisksd`. Check the documentation for the disk drive. Read `for i in udisksctl udisks umount.udisks2 ; do man $i; done`

Comment: When running the journalctl command I can see a few drive errors for `blk_update_request` and `Buffer I/O error`. These errors seem to appear in the logs for 19.04 too but I might try to reformat the drive next time I'm home to check there's nothing wrong there. I've read the drive documentation but I don't really see why 19.10 is treating it differently to 19.04. I may just add a cron job to mount the drive every few hours until I'm next home as I'm using it as a media server and it's annoying to have to manually fix every time!